# Plot function in 2D intensity plot in matlab

Tags: matlab, function, colors, plot, color-scheme

I'm trying to visualise a function into a more intuitive color-coded plot, which can be used into a image. I try to visualise the range in which fluorescent proteins can efficiently transfer energy from one to another. A very important factor in this process is the distance between the two proteins. Therefore I want to plot the theoretical graph of energy transfer as a function of distance on top of one of these proteins. 
I would like to have an 2D intensity plot which I can use to incorporate into my protein model.

The function describing efficient energy transfer is:

**E = R^6/(R^6+r^6)**

E = efficiency of energy transfer

R = Förster distance 50% chance of transfer

r = actual distance between the fluorescent proteins

Low values for r cause high values of E, meaning efficient energy transfer --> Green
High values for r cause low values of E, inefficient energy transfer --> red

My question is if someone can help me to transform the graph into a color-coded circle, where the middle of the circle corresponds with high E (green) and the borders are more red.

So far, I tried the mesh + surf function, but these require a matrix so that doesn't work.

I appreciate all your help, thank you for your replies!

Cheers,
Reinier

Comment: Could you provide some sample data, please. Also, I think it would be useful if you could post a simple manually created image/drawing of what you are trying to acheive.

Comment: I would like to transform a normal 2D graph into a circular intensity plot, in which the Y values are now color coded [link](http://www.phys.ksu.edu/personal/camcook/research_log_files/image017.jpg). The centre should be green for efficient transfer and the borders red. Regarding the data, the only known parameter is the R (which is 5.1 nm), so one can plot the energy tranfer efficiency for every distance 'r' between 0 up to 120 nm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly then

```
[R r] = meshgrid( 0.1:0.1:5 ); % define 2D inputs
E = (R.^6)./( R.^6 + r.^6 );   % compute 2D function
figure;
surf( R, r, E, 'EdgeColor','none'); % plot using surf
xlabel('R');
ylabel('r');
colormap( [ 1:-0.05:0; 0:.05:1;  zeros( 1, numel(0:.05:1) )]' ); % colormap red->green
```

What you get is
[image]

---

If you want to plot the 2D function `E( x,y ; R=5.1 )` with `r(x,y) = || x - y ||` then you can try

```
[X Y] = meshgrid(-120:1:120); % x,y range -120:120 nm
r = sqrt( X.^2 + Y.^2 );
R=5.1; % fixing R to 5.1 nm
figure;
surf( X, Y, (R.^6)./( R.^6 + r.^6 ), 'EdgeColor','none');
xlabel('X[nm]');
ylabel('Y[nm]');
zlabel('E');
colormap( [ 1:-0.05:0; 0:.05:1;  zeros( 1, numel(0:.05:1) )]' );
colorbar;
```

In that case you'll get
[image]

Comment: The second part is exactly what I needed. I changed three things:
1. I changed R = 5.1 to R = 51 
2. The axis are not in [nm] but in [Å]
3. I added one extra line of code    view(2); %generates 2D image of 3D plot

Thanks alot!